# Definition of Stationary Increments

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, poisson-process

What is a simple definition of Stationary Increments?

I saw that: $X_t - X_s = X_{t-s}$

How does this relate to the property of being a stationary process? Or even a weakly stationary process, that:

$E(X_t)=0$ and $Cov(X_t, X_{t+u})$ is a function of u

Comment: Stationary increments has nothing to do with stationary processes. These are two totally different notions...

Comment: So $X_t - X_s = X_{t-s}$ is just the definition?

Comment: Why does the poisson process have it? Maybe a simple proof?

Comment: $X_t-X_s = X_{t-s}$ **in distribution** is the definition of stationary increments, yes. What's your definition of a Poisson process?